# How to access or show popup from android Recents build-in button

Tags: android, menu, popup

I am trying to show the popup from android third button also called 'Recents' button one like whatsapp. Here is my screenshot which I want to achieve.
[image]

**Edit**

Popup must show from the right most button click.

[image]

Can anyone help me how can I access that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu on your picture is called 'overflow menu' and it shows action bar items that don't fit into the action bar (there is not enough space for them). It's shown at the bottom of the screen because your device has Menu button (on Samsung phones the most left button at the bottom of the screen).

Please note that the menu pops up from overflow button (three dots) in the top right corner if your device doesn't have Menu button. Refer [Action bar official guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html).

You can add items to overflow menu by specifying `android:showAsAction="never"` in you menu.xml file. It would look like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/item0"
    android:icon="@drawable/icn_info"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Action bar item"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Item 1 in overflow"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/item2"
    android:orderInCategory="20"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Item 2 in overflow"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/item3"
    android:orderInCategory="30"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Item 3 in overflow"/>

</menu>
```

**EDIT**:
As you can see, my device doesn't have Menu button at the bottom, so my WhatsApp shows overflow button in Action bar and overflow menu is coming from there:

### [image]

### **EDIT 2:**

Now I get your point. However, overriding Recents button is highly discouraged because it causes bad user experience. Recents button is never used for showing menu, it is used for showing Recent apps / documents.
Also, some devices don't even have this button (e.g. some Samsung devices use long press on Home button to show Recents).

Comment: I know menu which is in actionbar..But I want one same like whatsapp which access the phone's third button

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by "phone's third button", but we are most probably talking about the same menu. Some devices have device Menu button (one of the three buttons at the bottom of the screen) and show overflow menu coming from the bottom of the screen. Those that don't show overflow button (three dots) in action bar and overflow menu coming from that location.

Comment: @micky I have added example of WhatsApp on a device without the bottom Menu button.